# Self Updating ORM

Tags: database, linq-to-sql, orm

I have been using LinqToSQL for quite a while as well as using Devart, for some projects. Are there any ORMs that will update with your DB schema?

I understand that most of these products are meant to be used when you DB schema is already nailed down, but I find that that's in a perfect world, unfortunately, I don't develop in one.

There are a number of ORM's out there for .net developers (Entity Framework, DevArt, telerik OpenAccess, Etc.) most of which give you the ability to update your DAL by just a few clicks of your mouse. Like mentioned below, I am thinking that by scheduling a batch file to run every so many minutes or hours may be the best way to mimic Real-time updating.

Comment: In the real world, database schemas change all the time.  ORMs have been built to deal with this.  LinqToSql has a tool called SQLMetal that will read the current schema, but in general other ORMs are much easier to keep up to date with the schema.  This is not an area where LinqToSql is strong.  I'm not familiar with Devart's ORM.

Comment: We are a small shop, and currently everything we do, data access wise, is with untyped data sets which gives us pretty good flexibility most of the time, yet at the same time it gets us in trouble handling nulls, strings, dates etc. Consequently, I'm looking for something that gives us somewhat of the same flexibility, yet can move us away from some of those "oh crap" moments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LINQ to SQL you can just recreate all tables and regenerate the model when the schema changes. This is actually quite convenient. You can recreate individual tables, too.

Comment: I am using VS 2008, and I have only known it to change things if you drag and drop tables/views/stored procedures, rather than by some way of automation.

Comment: What did it change? Custom settings are lost, of course. That's why I don't customize the model. It is much better than typed datasets.

Comment: Say if you make a change to your table definition, if I drop the table in my dbml, then drag-and-drop the table back onto the designer, everything updates (all the changes are displayed, IntelliSense etc.)I was just wondering if there was something out there that would check, behind-the-scenes, or on-demand and change the dbml without the drop/drag-and-drop. If I'm missing something on the LtoS designer or Visual Studio 2008 that gives me this functionality, I would love to learn where it is and how to use it. Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing like this, alas. You can regenerate the dbml using sqlmetal.exe. Make a reusable .bat for this. This will come pretty clsoe to being automatic.